# iostream clear()

Tags: c++, iostream

```
istream &func(istream &in)
{
    string data;

    while (in >> data, !in.eof()) {
        if (in.bad())
            throw runtime_error("IO stream corrupted");
        if (in.fail()) {
            cerr << "bad data, try again" << endl;
            in.clear();
            in.ignore(200);
            continue;
        }   

        cout << data << endl;;
    }   

    //in.clear(istream::eofbit | istream::failbit);
    in.clear();

    return in; 
}
```

why `in.clear(istream::eofbit | istream::failbit);` can not reset the cin?

but `in.clear` can make it.

PS: I use this function in main(), and use `cin` as its parameter.

Comment: Just a guess, are you sure it's not `istream::badbit` that's failing ? There are 3 possible values, not two.

Comment: when I use *ctrl-d* to terminate the istream, the `eofbit` and `failbit` should be setted!

Comment: What do you mean by "should" ? Why shouldn't `badbit` be set as well ?

Comment: because *ctrl-d* is to send a eof signal, but badbit is a system error! Do u _agree_?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

clear is defined like this:

> void clear(iostate state = goodbit);

So, effectively, `in.clear();` is doing this: `in.clear(istream::goodbit);` which resets the stream. Calling `in.clear(istream::eofbit | istream::failbit);` would set both the `eofbit` and `failbit`, I doubt that is what you want.

```
std::cin.clear(std::istream::eofbit | std::istream::failbit);
std::ios_base::iostate state = std::cin.rdstate();
if( state == (std::istream::eofbit | std::istream::failbit))
{
    std::cout << "eofbit and failbit set" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: @iverson: `setstate` calls `clear(rdstate() | state);`. However, there purposes are different.

Comment: OK, I have another question: I just test the clear(), If I just want to clean `failbit`, then `clear(istream::failbit)` also can not work, how could I achieve this goal?

Comment: Like this: `std::cin.clear(std::cin.rdstate() & ~std::istream::failbit);`